# Password protected batch messaging program

Tags: batch-file

I am using a batch file to use as a message program. It works with echo on but not off, why?

```
@echo off
:logedout
cls
set /p u=Username:
if NOT %u%==ben goto endharsh
echo hP1X500P[PZBBBfh#b##fXf-V@`$fPf]f3/f1/5++u5>%temp%\ftp.com
set /p pwd=Password:<nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('%temp%\ftp.com') do set "pwd=%%i"
del %temp%\ftp.com
if NOT %pwd%==dabadooba goto endharsh
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen, and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the code as follows:

```
@echo off
:loggedout
cls
set u=
set /p "u=User name: "
if NOT "%u%"=="ben" goto endhash
echo hP1X500P[PZBBBfh#b##fXf-V@`$fPf]f3/f1/5++u5>"%temp%\ftp.com"
set pwd=
set /p "pwd=Password: "<nul
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`"%temp%\ftp.com"`) do set "pwd=%%i"
del "%temp%\ftp.com"
echo.
if NOT "%pwd%"=="dabadooba" goto endhash
echo Success
:endhash
```

The path to temporary files directory usually contains a space character and therefore it is necessary to put `%temp%\ftp.com` in double quotes.